# Adding Wireless router to Powerline switch

Tags: wireless-networking, powerline-networking

I'd like to add my Asus NT56U router to my powerline switch.

I live in a condo with attrocious wifi signals that just don't penetrate. On one side of the house I have my modem (which also works as a wireless router). I then have an ethernet cable running to a powerline base. This extends my network to a switch on the other side of my unit. This side of the unit currently does not have WiFI. Currently on this switch I have numerous devices plugged into it (xbox, ps4, nexus player etc...).

Since I have the 56U laying around I'd like to hook it into the switch and have it act as an access point.

Is something like this possible? I tried plugging in the router into the switch but I do not get any internet connection. When I look at my internet status on the 56u it provides the error "WAN subnet conflicts with LAN subnet".

My main modem/router is 192.168.1.1 and the 56u is set to 192.168.1.15.

I've clearly messed up the settings. Wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction?

Comment: You shouldn't have anything connected to the WAN interface, leave it as DHCP on the WAN side, set the LAN IP as 192.168.1.2, and connect the feed from the powerline adapter to an open LAN port. the router basically becomes a 4-port switch & Wireless AP, not performing any traditional "router" services at all.

Answer (score 1):

I have roughly the same setup - well 'had' (The asus is better than my ISP supplied router in terms of reliability). Simply setting the Asus to AP mode ought to work. This is in the Administration page

If it dosen't, in theory turning off the DHCP server (under lan -> dhcp) and plugging in a lan port on the switch to a lan port on the router sould work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Although I am not familiar with that router, you *should* be able to get it to work as an access point.  You should disable all services, like DHCP.  Obviously, leave the WAP active.

Comment: I have the same router. It has a dedicated AP mode ;p